# React useState Hook not updating state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am working on a Memory Game Project in React. I have an array of pokemon objects (since I use those as input for the game) and I set the *nextPokemon* in state to be an object at a random index in said *pokemonsArray*. Afterwards, I am adding the nextPokemon to an array called *renderedPokemon*, which I map over in the render function and create a button for every one of them. Now I already found out that if I have multiple state setters in one place, they get batched together and therefore it makes sense for my *renderedPokemon* array to receive an empty object when I add *nextPokemon* to it, because *nextPokemon* hasn't been evaluated yet. I added my code at the bottom, because I still have issues with a lot of it, which is:

**a)** understanding why setNextPokemon doesn't work, because it is the first process in line and doesn't even rely on previously set state, therefore batching it together with other state setters shouldn't be an issue

**b)** getting to know how updater functions help me since in setRenderedPokemon, using for example "prev => prev + x" doesn't help - I don't rely on previous values from the same state but from another state

You can see the code below. Any help is be appreciated.

```js
    const [pokemonsArray, setPokemonArray] = useState(pokemons);
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
    const [renderedPokemon, setRenderedPokemon] = useState([]);
    const [nextPokemon, setNextPokemon] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
         for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
              if (score === 49) {
                 return
              } else if (renderedPokemon.length == 0) {
                        setNextPokemon(pokemonsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 49)]);
                        setRenderedPokemon(nextPokemon);
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Before trying to debug this, keep in mind that all setState calls are asynchronous.

Comment: When you call `setRenderedPokemon`, `nextPokemon` hasn't been updated yet.  Fortunately, you know the value you're updating it to already, so you can use that value instead.

Comment: @David How would the syntax for adding that updated value to setRenderedPokemon instead look like?

Comment: @GianlucaJahn: It would be the same syntax any time you want to pass the same value to two different functions.  Store the new value for `nextPokemon` in a variable.  Pass that variable to `setNextPokemon`.  Pass that variable to `setRenderedPokemon`.